# How to detect REST API request is from mobile or from PC in spring 6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mobile

In Spring 5, I was using `org.springframework.mobile` jar and `Device` class to detect if REST request is from mobile or not.

code:

```
if (device.isMobile() || device.isTablet()) {
                return true;
            }
```

But in spring 6, `org.springframework.mobile` jar is removed.

Is there any other way to check if REST request is from mobile or not.

Comment: This was never part of Spring but of Spring Mobile which has been abondonded years ago. As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77992942/spring-framework-6-not-supporting-spring-mobiles-latest-version-1-1-5-release).

Comment: any alternate way to check...

Comment: You can copy the code from Spring Mobile (the interceptor or filter) that adds that information and adapt it to the changes. Next to that as it has been abandoned long ago it probably doesn't even support all devices already especially newer ones.

Answer (score 1):

The whole library Spring Mobile has been abandoned because there is no reliable way to determine who (what device) is the sender of HTTP request. The client can set some information in the header like `User-Agent` but it is not mandatory.

The best option for you as the owner of REST API is to define an additional parameter in the API and let your clients set it properly. For example `deviceType=mobile`.

If it is not doable then you can try to check the above mentioned `User-Agent` key of the header using `HttpServletRequest.getHeader()`.